# How can I make windows go fullscreen when snapping to the top of the screen in xfce?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

You know how in unity when you grab a window and snap it to the top of the screen it will go fullscreen? Im currently using xubuntu but when I snap the window to the top it will just fill the top half of the screen. I wanna know if there is a way in xfce to make windows go full screen when snaping to the top while still keeping that "mosaic" snap just in the sides.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In xfce you have to double click on the top to get fullscreen.

Yet I don't know about settings to change the snapping to going fullscreen.

Any setting are at Settings Manager -> Window Manager -> Advanced or Settings Manager -> Window Manager Tweaks